# White text on a UITextView action sheet

Tags: ios, uitextview

When tapping and holding an action sheet or menu controller shows up but the text is white, what could be causing this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I guess you have changed some appearance in your app that is causing this

Answer (score 2):

Check for any override that maybe causing the problem.

Look for something like this in `IOS7` delegate `- willPresentActionSheet:` to change colors..

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            [button setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
}
```

in iOS8 it's something like this i think:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [actionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];
if ([alertController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])
{
    alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

**Edit**

I was searching and testing maybe it was..

[image]

Under `- (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` try checking it out..

Answer (score 2):

You need to set following appearance for UIAlertController class for IOS 8.

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Another solution for IOS7+

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

May this help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it was

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

in the AppDelegate.

Although I'm sure it could be on the UIAlertController or UIActionSheet in other cases. 0yeoj's answer of checking the tint on the UIAlertController lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Oh, you got it.. :) (high five)! Glad to help.. :)